# Parsing XML with pairs of elements using XDocument and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to use `XDocument` to parse an xml document, however I am pretty new to XML and have only primarily used JSON in the past.  So far I can parse each report name but am stuck with trying to parse the parameter list. How do I parse the parameter list when theres no node differentiating the different parameters?

```
var reports = xml.Descendants("Report").Select(reportElement => new
{
    Name = reportElement.Attribute("Name").Value,
    Parameters = reportElement.Descendants("ParameterList").Select(parameter => new
    {
    })
});
```

XML:

```
<ReportList>
    <Report Name="JobNotClose">
        <ParameterList>
            <Name>@StationCode</Name><Value>LAX</Value>
            <Name>@ShipmentType</Name><Value>SE|SI</Value>
        </ParameterList>
    </Report>
    <Report Name="JobWithoutSales">
        <ParameterList>
            <Name>@StationCode</Name><Value>PA</Value>
            <Name>@JobDateFrom</Name><Value>2013-10-1</Value>
            <Name>@JobDateTo</Name><Value>2013-10-31</Value>
        </ParameterList>
    </Report>
</ReportList>
```

Comment: That xml looks a bit doggy to me. Isn't the param entry supposed to be  <Param Name=@StationCode, Value=PA /> ?

Comment: See that's what I asked, but no this is how it will be formatted as. if it was a <Param> node i'd just use `.Descendants()` I'm not really sure what to do with it structured like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to merge parameter names sequence with parameter values sequence:

```
var reports = from r in xml.Root.Elements("Report")
              let parameters = r.Element("ParameterList")
              select new {
                  Name = (string)r.Attribute("Name"),
                  Parameters = parameters.Elements("Name")
                                         .Zip(parameters.Elements("Value"), 
                                              (n,v) => new { 
                                                  Name = (string)n, 
                                                  Value = (string)v 
                                              })
              };
```

That gives following reports collection:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "JobNotClose",
    "Parameters": [
      {
        "Name": "@StationCode",
        "Value": "LAX"
      },
      {
        "Name": "@ShipmentType",
        "Value": "SE|SI"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "JobWithoutSales",
    "Parameters": [
      {
        "Name": "@StationCode",
        "Value": "PA"
      },
      {
        "Name": "@JobDateFrom",
        "Value": "2013-10-1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "@JobDateTo",
        "Value": "2013-10-31"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (and by *try* I mean *use*):

```
var reports = xml.Descendants("Report").Select(reportElement => new
{
    Name = reportElement.Attribute("Name").Value,
    Parameters = reportElement.Descendants("ParameterList").Select(parameter => 
    {
        List<string> names = parameter.Elements("Name").Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
        List<string> values = parameter.Elements("Value").Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();

        List<object>  pairs=new List<object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            pairs.Add(new { Name = names[i], Value = values[i] });
        }

        return pairs;                    
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

You can remove both `ToList()` calls. It just made it easier to test. Of course, there's the possibility that in your XML, the `<Name> <Value>` tags are not always complete (i.e. `Name` without `Value`). You can check that before doing the `for` loop.

EDIT: An alternative:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>> rep = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>>();

foreach (XElement report in xml.Elements("Report"))
{
    rep.Add(report.Attribute("Name").Value, new List<Tuple<string, string>>());

    List<string> names = report.Elements("ParameterList").FirstOrDefault().Elements("Name").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
    List<string> values = report.Elements("ParameterList").FirstOrDefault().Elements("Value").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
         rep[report.Attribute("Name").Value].Add(new Tuple<string, string>(names[i], values[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make Parameters a List of Lists? I may have written it incorrectly from the beginning of Parameter.  To my understanding, each report will only contain one ParameterList node, and within it multiple <Name><Value> pairs

Comment: @ChaoticLoki, yes, it does make it a list of lists. This is drawback for this method. There are other approaches too. This one was built upon your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work.

You could take ParameterList elements as an IEnumerable using XNode.ElementsAfterSelf.
Then loop through the result set and assume the elements are in pairs.

This will essentially give you a way to parse the elements in the order they appear in the ParameterList without worrying about .Descendants messing with the order.

Of course, the big assumption here is that the elements are always in pairs.